# Next.js + RTK Query Server-Side-Rendering throws 500 error on Deployment but works fine after build locally

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, getserversideprops

I am building an app using NextJS and RTK Query. Locally after the build everything works as expected. However after deploy on Vercel the server-side rendering logic (getServerSideProps for 2 pages) throws 500 error.

I was following [redux](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/server-side-rendering) documentation and [example](https://github.com/phryneas/ssr-experiments/tree/main/nextjs-blog)  attached to redux documentation.

I have added [rehydration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpXuj.png) to all api services.
I have created [wrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fRYy.png) around the store.
I used **wrapper** in getServerSideProps function [in Home component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJLpQ.png) and added logic for next to call the api's on the server side.

Locally: in the Home component props, I receive all data as expected. The NextJS server sends the premade HTML as expected.
[premade HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo6vg.png)

Deployed: throws [500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfrcU.png): for Home component (page) But all the other pages that doesn't use SSR works 100% fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution [here](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/issues/2214). So, I had a version 13.5.4 of Next and downgraded it to 13.5.3. Additionally I installed core.js via "npm i core-js". One of these or both of them solved the problem.